# Is there a way to keep gmail from inheriting the last search in the Google toolbar?

Tags: gmail, search, google-toolbar

I don't know if it always did this, but it seems to have started recently.

If I type a search in the Google toolbar, then later open up g-mail in the same browser instance, the gmail search box is pre-filled with the search from the google toolbar and my inbox is filtered by that search criteria.

This is very annoying, how can I make it stop doing that?

Comment: In Firefox, it's the same with the upper right search

Comment: I got into the habit of having Gmail and Google Calendar auto-open in their own tabs.  Then, when things get too busy, I use **snipe** to find the correct tab.   In the Chrome web store, see `Extensions --> Productivity --> Snipe`

Answer (score 1):

That might be due to AutoFill option in the browser. Try turning that off.

Or check to see if you have some plugin installed that does this behavior.